# how to delete a specific element of list in mvc?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

guys this is my home controller where i declared controllers and create list class and action views.

```
namespace MvcApplication6.Controllers
{

public class Trains
{
    public string tname { get; set; }
    public int tno { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}


public class HomeController : Controller
{


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.message = "Welcome to trains list!";



        return View();

    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        List<Trains> details = new List<Trains>() { };
        details.Add(new Trains() { tname = "vaigai", tno = 123, from = "Chennai", to = "trichy" });
        details.Add(new Trains() { tname = "express", tno = 456, from = "banglore", to = "chennai" });

        return View(details);
    }
```

and this is my html page where i getting the controllers to get display the list in one by one in table

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "delete";
}


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Available Trains";
}

@model List<MvcApplication6.Controllers.Trains>
<h2>list of available trains are:</h2>
<p> 
 <table>
         <tr>
             <th>TRAIN NAME</th>
             <th>TRAIN NUMBER</th>
             <th>FROM</th>
             <th>TO</th>
             <th>Delete</th>
         </tr>

@foreach (var item in @Model)
{
    <tr style="color: blue">
        <td>@item.tname</td>
        <td>@item.tno</td>
        <td>@item.from</td>
        <td>@item.to</td>
        <td> @Html.ActionLink("Delete","About",new{i = item.tno})</td>
    </tr>
}
 </table>
```

now i want to delete a element in list and display the remaining elements. i tried different methods but the whole list deleting or nothing is deleted.

Comment: `i tried different methods` Show us those attempts.

Comment: What element do you want to delete? And can you show us what you have done so far

Comment: Why not use database and store items instead of using static lists?

Comment: @SusenMaharjan Why ? Does it change anything on his issue ? He might just testing stuff and doesn't need a DB atm.

Comment: You have to put the details object out of the action method so that it can be viewed from a delete method that could just implement a simple Linq query for selected item removal

Comment: @Cesar no, but he definitely needs a means to get that list not being instantiated every time the controller's constructor is called. It's either a DB or a mock object which is by far harder to understand for someone that is (like me!) still new at programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the model object out of the action method, it needs to be accessible from different methods.

I'd go with something like this:

```
public class TrainManagerController : Controller
{
    // the train list is set at Controller level
    private List<Trains> TrainList;

    // and populated when the controller is instantiated
    public TrainManagerController(List<Trains> trainList)
    {
        TrainList = trainList;
    }

    // this calls the view with the train list you have at the moment
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(TrainList);
    }

    // this deletes the train, then calls the index view.
    public RedirectToRouteResult DeleteFromList(int TrainNumber)
    {
        TrainList.Remove(TrainList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.tno == TrainNumber));
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

In the view:

```
@foreach (var item in @Model)
{
    <tr style="color: blue">
        <td>@item.tname</td>
        <td>@item.tno</td>
        <td>@item.from</td>
        <td>@item.to</td>
        <td> @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteFromList", new {TrainNumber = item.tno})</td>
    </tr>
}
```

There is a piece missing though: how do you pass the `List<Trains>` object to the constructor arguments? Usually, that's done by [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), where -in cases like this- a DB connection is also implemented, so you request an interface (let's call it ITrains here) and a properly configured third-party component gives you a populated List.

I know the topic can give you quite a headache, so you can skip that for brevity until you grasp the basics on how controllers and action methods work, and build that object differently:

Create a new `TrainContext` class that will keep the list of the trains and will have the methods to deal with this list (you need to delete, remember?):

```
public class TrainContext
{
    private static List<Trains> trainList = null;

    public TrainContext()
    {
        if (trainList == null)
        {
            trainList = new List<Trains>();
            trainList.Add(new Trains() { tname = "vaigai", tno = 123, from = "Chennai", to = "trichy" });
            trainList.Add(new Trains() { tname = "express", tno = 456, from = "banglore", to = "chennai" });
        }
    }

    public List<Trains> GetTrains()
    {
        return trainList;
    }

    public void Delete(int TrainNumber)
    {
        if (trainList.Count > 0)
            trainList.Remove(trainList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.tno == TrainNumber));
    }
}
```

so that you can just call that static list any time the TrainManager controller is requested. Now we have to change the controller accordingly

```
public class TrainManagerController : Controller
{
    private TrainContext context;

    public TrainManagerController()
    {
        context = new TrainContext();
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(context.GetTrains());
    }

    public RedirectToRouteResult DeleteFromList(int TrainNumber)
    {
        context.Delete(TrainNumber);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Now you have an object that will consistently store you list of trains and you can do whatever you want with that.